# Sum Iteration from $n$ to $n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a simple question regarding the definition of the sum:

$$\sum_{k=n}^n a_k$$

Does this count as $0$ iterations or as $1$ iteration?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: The sum is equal to $a_n$, i.e.: $$ \sum_{k = n}^n a_k = a_n $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $$\sum_{k=i}^n a_k$$ means that you start at $k=i$ and stop incrementing when $k$ is equal to $n$. That is, you sum over all integers $k$ such that $i \le k \le n$.
So in the context of $\sum\limits_{k=n}^n a_k$, we start at $k=n$, and never increment. But we still have the $k=n$ term, so the sum is $a_n$.

A sum with zero terms, such as $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{-1} a_k$, is generally taken to be the additive identity, $0$. The sum has zero terms as there are no integers $k$ such that $0 \le k \le -1$.